# jQuery DataTables - I cannot get the desired effect I want

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, themeroller

I'm not sure how much information you'll need to help me, so let me know if I need to provide more.

I'm using jQuery DataTables with Themeroller. I'm trying to accomplish this look:

[image]

However, no matter what I try, this is what I get:

[image]

I've highlighted in red the areas I'm having an issue with. Basically it's the header and the footer. I know the image is a bit hard to see, but it's as if the header and footer blocks are only partially being drawn. According to Chrome the area is 1600px by 12px. It looks like it should be at least 50px or more.

I'm including the following .css files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> - The Exchange Site</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

My JavaScript at the bottom of my HTML is as follows:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        oTable = $('#buyerNotification').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
        });
    });
```

When I inspect the page in Chrome, no errors are being generated. If it would help to include more, I can do so, like my HTML, but there is a lot of it.

Comment: Can you show your html too?  Just one tbody row should be good but seeing the table structure would be good. so your table.. thead.. tbody with one row

Comment: I don't think seeing the HTML would be particularly helpful; it's all generated by the DataTables API. Randy, it's been so long since I implemented mine that I don't remember why, but I recall keeping some of the base DataTables CSS even though I also use jQuery UI. I have also added some of my own custom rules to supplement jQuery UI; looks like your headers and footers don't have layout. Pick a selector that encapsulates them and try putting "overflow: hidden" on them.

Comment: it's very useful when we want to test in a fiddle/jsbin to see what the issue really is and to see if we can replicate it

Comment: DataTables has its own useful sandbox: http://live.datatables.net/ -- Randy, also just noticed the inclusion of both a jQuery UI CSS and a "themeroller" CSS... there should be only one jQuery UI CSS file of any type, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: ok, can you replicate his issue there?

Comment: that shouldn't affect anything having both css.. besides waste of space - by using the `bJQueryUI:true` it will use the themeroller css

Comment: @GregPettit - You can attribute that to not really knowing what I'm doing. I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Here - have both the regular css and themeroller css.. I don't know where/how you're getting that extra padding or whatever it above and below the table [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/pqspN/)

Comment: Here's one not using one of jQuery UI's theme but the default [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/a9NNY/) - I see what you're talking about now.  It shows up fine here though

Comment: what version of jQuery.. jQueryUI/jQueryUI.css are you using?  I think I found what's causing it but would need more info

Comment: @wirey - Thank you very much. Here is the info you want. jQueryUI is  - v1.10.2 - 2013-03-14

Comment: @wirey - I'm using 1.10.1 of jquery-ui.js

Comment: have you tried using the older jQuery UI ? like 1.9.2? just for testing to see if it makes any difference

Comment: @wirey - Yes I was using an earlier version and then retrieved the latest version of the various files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26751/discussion-between-wirey-and-randy-minder)

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/themes.html).  Have you specified the `"bJQueryUI": true` option?

Comment: Nevermind.  You just added the javascript and the option is there.